# synchronization on 2 ubercart instances

Tags: ubercart

Because of problems with multi-currency ubecart, I am thinking about creating 2 identical e-shops for 2 countries with different currencies. One important thing worries me - stock levels. Is there any way to synchronize stock levels data between multiple drupal/ubercart installations? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which Drupal & UC Version ?

Comment: @NikhilM I use drupal 6 ubercart 2

Comment: Here i a great tut to do **Multicurrency** http://vintagedigital.net/content/how-add-multicurrency-support-ubercart in ubercart 2

Comment: @NikhilM thank you, actually I have already built 2 separate sites (the question was asked almost 1 year ago) What I am looking for now is really only the way of synchronising stock levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in the stock module is a function for set stock level and you also need a custom xml-rpc client/server functions for both instances.

Comment: do I need to write my own module for that?

Comment: Yes you need write custom module. This module should be on both instances. You can use native drupal xml-rpc interface. When you will edit stock level in the instance no. 1 you will trigger your custom xml-rpc client function and you will send a message with new stock level to your custom xml-rpc server function in the instance no. 2 and remotely you will edit stock level and vice versa. Sorry for my english..

Comment: sounds great, unfortunately I am not a programmer. Thank you.